# how to get the token key by oauth2.0

Tags: jquery, ajax, oauth-2.0

I am using AJAX to get the token key and then transfer to another page for checking the token access key has been generated or not. Here is my code. The error I receive is "Bad Request Status".

```js
function Login() {
  var mod = {
    UserName: $("#name").val(),
    Password: $("#pass").val(),
    grant_type: 'password'
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: '/token',
    method: 'Post',
    data: JSON.stringify(mod),
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-url;',
    success: function(response) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.access_token);
      window.location.href = "Data.html";
    },
    error: function(response) {
    }
  })
```

Comment: Does server returns a detailed error message on response body?

Comment: no there is a console showing error 400 bad request

Comment: Using wrong contentType for sending json...or...if need to send form encoded data don't stringify it

Comment: @charlietfl is correct. Either change content-type to `application/json` or use urlencoded object